# Trying to integrate PHPMailer with my login/registration form

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

So I'm trying to implement PHPMailer for my registration form but getting an error when it comes to processing the verification email.

It'll add the account to my database fine but without the email being sent.

I get the error:

Notice: Use of undefined constant phpmailer - 
assumed 'phpmailer' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/login/scripts/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 27
The file phpmailer.php could not be found.

The code in PHPMailerAutoload.php

```
function PHPMailerAutoload($MailSender)
{
    //Can't use __DIR__ as it's only in PHP 5.3+
    $filename = dirname(phpmailer).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($MailSender).'.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    function __autoload($MailSender)
    {
        PHPMailerAutoload($MailSender);
    }
}
```

This is my file structure:

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHkiE.png)

FIXED!

Code should be:

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE)__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($MailSender).'.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check line

`$filename = dirname(phpmailer).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($MailSender).'.php';`

this:

`dirname(phpmailer)`

do you mean `$phpmailer`?

Comment: That's the correct line but its supposed to be the filename I'm pretty sure as it was __FILE__ when I had downloaded it.

Comment: @J.Charnock try `dirname('phpmailer')`

Comment: Sorry, I was overcomplicating things and it was supposed to be left as FILE. Changed it back to how it was and it works! Hey Presto